# MYSQL database table capping columns at 22

Tags: mysql

Can't seem to find anything about this on google.
I have a rather large DB, and in one of my tables, (there are 8 each with around 20-40 columns) I tried to add another 20 columns. They end up showing as empty names in the dropdown "show columns" dropdown list in phpmyadmin. However, if I click edit on one of the entries, the name shows up. At first I thought maybe I hit the max char limit or something funny like that, but I can create new columns in other tables within the same DB.

Any ideas on what might be happening?

Heres the EXPORT of the table

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.5.2.2
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Nov 02, 2012 at 12:49 PM
-- Server version: 5.5.27
-- PHP Version: 5.4.7

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `memberships`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `upload`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `upload` (
  `id` int(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `chk_long` enum('off','on') NOT NULL,
  `chk_short` enum('off','on') NOT NULL,
  `chk_bass` enum('off','on') NOT NULL,
  `chk_mid` enum('off','on') NOT NULL,
  `chk_hi` enum('off','on') NOT NULL,
  `chk_stereo` enum('off','on') NOT NULL,
  `chk_mono` enum('off','on') NOT NULL,
  `chk_left` enum('off','on') NOT NULL,
  `chk_right` enum('off','on') NOT NULL,
  `chk_noteseq` enum('off','on') NOT NULL,
  `chk_sample` enum('off','on') NOT NULL,
  `chk_midi` enum('off','on') NOT NULL,
  `var_keynote` enum('None','A','A#','B','C','C#','D','D#','E','F','F#','G','G#') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'None',
  `box_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `box_desc` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `sample_url` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `rating` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `t_up` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `t_down` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `category` enum('drums','horror','remixraw','acapella','talk','beatbox','robot','synth','object','arpeggio','bass','lead','loop','pad','soundfx','wobble','misc') NOT NULL,
  `ambient` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `breakbeat` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `disco` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `downtempo` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `drumandbass` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `dub` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `dubstep` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `electro` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `electronica` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `electronic rock` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `eurodance` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `hardcore` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `harddance` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `house` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `industrial` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `glitch` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `jungle` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `techno` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `trance` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `chiptune` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=51 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `upload`
--

INSERT INTO `upload` (`id`, `username`, `chk_long`, `chk_short`, `chk_bass`, `chk_mid`, `chk_hi`, `chk_stereo`, `chk_mono`, `chk_left`, `chk_right`, `chk_noteseq`, `chk_sample`, `chk_midi`, `var_keynote`, `box_name`, `box_desc`, `sample_url`, `rating`, `t_up`, `t_down`, `category`, `ambient`, `breakbeat`, `disco`, `downtempo`, `drumandbass`, `dub`, `dubstep`, `electro`, `electronica`, `electronic rock`, `eurodance`, `hardcore`, `harddance`, `house`, `industrial`, `glitch`, `jungle`, `techno`, `trance`, `chiptune`) VALUES
(2, 'VVV', 'on', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'on', 'on', 'off', 'on', 'on', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'A#', 'sample for samplewars', 'asd', '../samples/65621__otherthings__inhale-10115b.wav', 903, 3249, 2346, 'drums', 21, 4, 2, 5, 46, 23, 75, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(4, 'VVV', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'None', 'bang', 'gg', '../samples/bang0_5.wav', 6, 23456, 23450, 'drums', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(5, 'VVV', 'off', 'on', 'on', 'off', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'B', 'gfsdg', 'dsfgfsdg', '../samples/arc_4.wav', 1999, 2345, 346, 'drums', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(6, 'VVV', 'off', 'on', 'on', 'off', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'B', 'dfgdg', 'dsfgfsdgdfg', '../samples/bdeHOE36024hard1.wav', -177, 58, 235, 'drums', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(7, 'VVV', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'on', 'on', 'on', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'None', 'hat', 'hattattatt', '../samples/Hat20.wav', 11, 20, 9, 'drums', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(8, 'VVV', 'off', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'None', 'baasssss', 'ssas', '../samples/bass39.wav', 0, 0, 0, 'drums', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(9, 'VVV', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'None', 'sdgs', 'dfgdsg', '../samples/DJ SAMPLES VOL 2 (1).wav', 0, 0, 0, 'drums', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(10, 'VVV', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'None', 'fygjfs', 'fjktyuiytdtg', '../samples/DJ SAMPLES VOL 2 (18).wav', 0, 0, 0, 'drums', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(11, 'VVV', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'None', 'retyytj', 'r6tfydzxg', '../samples/DJ SAMPLES VOL 2 (531).wav', 0, 0, 0, 'drums', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(12, 'VVV', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'None', 'fghsdg', 'dfgnhg', '../samples/DJ SAMPLES VOL 2 (643).wav', 0, 0, 0, 'drums', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(13, 'VVV', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'None', 'dsfb', 'rsatey', '../samples/DJ SAMPLES VOL 2 (537).wav', 0, 0, 0, 'drums', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(14, 'VVV', 'off', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'None', 'dgb', 'dbgdb', '../samples/Bassdrum Gated.wav', 0, 0, 0, 'drums', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(15, 'VVV', 'off', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'None', 'gxhn', 'dbgdb', '../samples/Snare 3.wav', 0, 0, 0, 'drums', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(16, 'VVV', 'off', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'None', 'toml', 'dbgdb', '../samples/Tom L.wav', 0, 0, 0, 'drums', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(17, 'VVV', 'off', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'None', 'hita', 'dbgdb', '../samples/Hihat2.wav', 0, 0, 0, 'drums', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(18, 'VVV', 'off', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'None', 'bline', 'dbgdb', '../samples/Bassline3.wav', 0, 0, 0, 'drums', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(19, 'VVV', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'None', 'gfjutj', 'rfujuj', '../samples/Ambient2 loop.wav', 0, 0, 0, 'drums', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(20, 'VVV', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'None', 'xfh', 'rdh', '../samples/Deranged.wav', 0, 0, 0, 'drums', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(21, 'VVV', 'off', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'None', 'fxvxvz', 'zxbbxx', '../samples/tp1_Button_Perc_1.wav', 0, 0, 0, 'drums', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(22, 'VVV', 'off', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'None', 'cnn', 'ghj', '../samples/tp1_Tall_Perc_1.wav', 0, 0, 0, 'drums', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(23, 'VVV', 'off', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'None', 'cvgn', 'vcng', '../samples/tp1_Ear_Perc_1.wav', 0, 0, 0, 'drums', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(24, 'VVV', 'off', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'None', 'vbncvbn', 'vcbn', '../samples/baligator3.wav', 0, 0, 0, 'drums', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(25, 'VVV', 'off', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'None', 'evil', 'cbg', '../samples/evillaugh.wav', 0, 0, 0, 'drums', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(26, 'VVV', 'off', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'None', 'monster', 'xfxf', '../samples/monster.wav', 0, 0, 0, 'drums', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(27, 'VVV', 'off', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'None', 'fx1', 'xfxf', '../samples/VEE FX 000.wav', 0, 0, 0, 'drums', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(28, 'VVV', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'None', 'fx2', 'xfxf', '../samples/VEE FX 002.wav', 0, 0, 0, 'drums', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(29, 'VVV', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'None', 'fx4', 'xfxf', '../samples/VEE FX 004.wav', 0, 0, 0, 'drums', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(30, 'VVV', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'None', 'fx5', 'xfxf', '../samples/VEE FX 005.wav', 0, 0, 0, 'drums', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(31, 'VVV', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'None', 'fx6', 'xfxf', '../samples/VEE FX 006.wav', 0, 0, 0, 'drums', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(32, 'VVV', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'None', 'fx7', 'xfxf', '../samples/VEE FX 007.wav', 0, 0, 0, 'drums', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(33, 'VVV', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'None', 'fx12', 'xfxf', '../samples/VEE FX 012.wav', 0, 0, 0, 'drums', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(34, 'VVV', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'None', 'zxvcxz', '', '../samples/VEE Clap 009.wav', 0, 0, 0, 'drums', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(35, 'VVV', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'None', 'zxvcx', '', '../samples/VEE Clap 008.wav', 0, 0, 0, 'drums', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(36, 'VVV', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'None', 'sfcsdf', '', '../samples/VEE Clap 003.wav', 0, 0, 0, 'drums', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(37, 'VVV', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'None', 'sdaterw', '', '../samples/VEE Clap 010.wav', 0, 0, 0, 'drums', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(38, 'VVV', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'None', 'clap', '', '../samples/VEE Clap 042.wav', 0, 0, 0, 'drums', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(39, 'VVV', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'None', 'clap108', '', '../samples/VEE Clap 107.wav', 0, 0, 0, 'drums', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(40, 'VVV', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'None', 'clap15', '', '../samples/VEE Clap 015.wav', 0, 0, 0, 'drums', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(41, 'VVV', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'None', 'clap17', '', '../samples/VEE Clap 017.wav', 0, 0, 0, 'drums', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(42, 'VVV', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'None', 'clap22', '', '../samples/VEE Clap 022.wav', 0, 0, 0, 'drums', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(43, 'VVV', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'None', 'cllap35', '', '../samples/VEE Clap 035.wav', 0, 0, 0, 'drums', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(44, 'VVV', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'None', 'clla7', '', '../samples/VEE Clap 007.wav', 0, 0, 0, 'drums', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(45, 'VVV', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'None', 'clla7as', '', '../samples/VEE Clap 0212.wav', 0, 0, 0, 'drums', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(46, 'VVV', 'on', 'off', 'on', 'on', 'on', 'on', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'None', 'everybody talks', 'etalk', '../samples/badman.wav', 0, 0, 0, 'drums', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(47, 'VVV', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'None', 'sdafasfasdf', 'asdfasdfasdf', '../samples/perc120-31.wav', 0, 0, 0, 'robot', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(48, 'vvv2', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'None', 'dsfzsdf', 'sdfasdf', '../samples/explosion6.wav', 25, 27, 2, 'object', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(49, 'VVV', 'on', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'None', 'sdfsadf', 'asdfsadf', '../samples/kicks1100.wav', 0, 0, 0, 'drums', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(50, 'vvv2', 'on', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'off', 'B', 'dooooood', 'ada', 'tester', 0, 0, 0, 'synth', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: No, because you posted 0 code and we can only guess what's that mystical "show columns" dropdown list.

Comment: also just noticed I can't edit the NULL value that the cell has. Even if I manually edit it within the row's edit panel in phpmyadmin it still shows NULL in the table browse

Comment: Please show us some code

Comment: there's really no code, I'm trying to make the columns in phpmyadmin.

Comment: This is most probably not a MySQL issue but a PHPMyAdmin one. You are either using non-Latin characters in the names or the PHPMyAdmin has not been configured properly or you hit a bug (or all of the above).

Comment: Which columns aren't showing up? Sounds more like a phpMyAdmin bug.

Comment: it's everything below 'category'.

Comment: It's starting to really seem like it's a bug. Which is great. It's around the last couple files of code for this couple month project.

Comment: Does phpmyadmin has a refresh (the table's structure) action? (also try logging out and in again)

Comment: it has a refresh on the browse entries section, but doesn't seem to have one on the structure section. I also don't see a way to relog the user

Comment: Seems I can add valid rows in certain places. After the username, but not the id, not after category or in the middle of any of the chk's.

Comment: It seems the more I add, the more columns become NULL and disappear from the table browse layout after whatever i added. Is there a cap on columns?

Comment: Can you ditch phpmyadmin and use sqlyog or similar program to manage mysql?

Comment: You think it's only an interface problem? I don't mind not being able to view it if it works properly. Perhaps i'll just try some test fetches/updates and see if they work as meant to. It's just easier on xampp to use phpmyadmin imo

Comment: Err yeah, I guess you can see it's just a problem from the export too. The values are getting saved, just not displayed.